# Shell script needs to be run twice to work as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 1. Kill the process along with the screen
/usr/bin/pkill -f reportPrintingServer.jar

# 2. Start the printing server again.
/usr/bin/screen -S proRps -d -m /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/projects/pro/assets/report_printing_server/reportPrintingServer.jar
```

If I run them on terminal per lines, they work as expected. But if I run them in a shell script, I need to run it twice to work as expected. So the first run is to kill the process, and the second is to run the printing server again.

I am wondering if I can just run the shell script once, and it will kill and restart the printing server again.

Comment: It might be running too quickly? You can add a `sleep` command to make the script wait between the commands.

Comment: @KenSharp Thx for noticing it. Idk ubuntu has a sleep command. It's working properly now when I add 3 seconds sleep in between those 2 commands.

Comment: @choz Maybe add that as an answer ;)

Comment: @KenSharp Would you please add that as an answer?

Comment: Another option could be to make the script check that the process isn't running before trying to run it again, but this requires a loop and would use `sleep` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When entering the commands into the terminal yourself you are more than likely waiting for each command to complete.

When the same commands are run as part of a script they can complete too quickly. `pkill`, for example, will send the kill command but won't wait for the application to exit.

You can make the script wait for an amount of time using the `sleep` command.

For example:

```
/usr/bin/pkill -f reportPrintingServer.jar

# Wait a few seconds
sleep 5

/usr/bin/screen -S proRps -d -m /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/projects/pro/assets/report_printing_server/reportPrintingServer.jar
```